# allow admin to login as a standard user in yii

Tags: yii

I am working in yii basic and I need to show a list of all users to admin with login button if admin click on this button then admin should be login as that user and can access data of user. how I can achieve it.

Comment: In your admin, show all users to admin in Cgridview, Then create a view and edit button in cgridview to view the profile of user and edit of update information for that user and also if u have social network, then u can also update any user's status, profile pics, upload files etc. u don't need to add login button.

Comment: But my admin need it. My admin says to add user login button.

Comment: I think it will be more simple if you just make a CGridView table and show all the users with their name, email, etc and in last column, add an edit button (Replace the edit button with login button), When he will click on it, it will open users profile and he will be able to access all information through it of that user, update status, upload files to his profiles etc ..